# 3.7 V battery compatiblity?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-chemistry

Can I use 3.7V 400 mAH battery instead of 3.7 V, 520 mAH, 2.00 W ?

How much difference it can make ?

Sorry not more techical sound here...

Thanks !

Comment: The maximum charge it is able to store will be the main difference.  3.7V 400mAH will not last as long.

Comment: The smaller capacity battery will last a little over 75% as long as the larger battery.  Depending on the battery, it's peak instantaneous current draw may not be as much either, which may or may not affect your application depending on its maximum current draw.

Comment: thanks...my application needs 3.7 V, 520 mAH, 2.00 W...battery..if i use above 520 mAH it can harm my application or if above 3.7 V ?

Answer (score 1):

Basic math. Find the percentage. 520/100 * 400/? = (400 * 100) / 520 = 76.4.

A 400 mAh battery is 76.4% of the 520 mAh one. You will get 76% the run time. Less in practice due to non-linear changes.